# Помогите с циклом

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void act() {
        String phrase;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Да или нет?");
        String ans[] = {"да", "нет"};
        phrase = sc.next();
        phrase = phrase.toLowerCase(); //конвертируем всю строку в строчные буквы
        boolean a = phrase.equals(ans[0]);
        boolean b = phrase.equals(ans[1]);
        if (a || b) {
            System.out.println("На что ты ответил то?!");
        } else {
            while (!a || !b) {
                System.out.println("Я просто просил ответить 'да' или 'нет', не более!");
                phrase = sc.next();
                a = phrase.equals(ans[0]);
                b = phrase.equals(ans[1]);
                System.out.println(a);
                System.out.println(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Почему, если дело доходит до цикла, он исполняется вечно. Помогите исправить. Не понятно почему значение `a` и `b` не меняется на `false`.

Comment: Используйте `while(sc.hasNext()) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Вы когда вводите "да" или "нет" один из этих вариантов будет положительный, а второй отрицательный.

```
a = phrase.equals(ans[0]);
b = phrase.equals(ans[1]);
```

И условие

```
!a || !b
```

всегда будет истина. Делайте проверку по одному условию, а не по двум.

```
if(phrase.equals(ans[0])({
    a = true;
}else{
    a= false;
};
```

Как-то так